# notation question re: function space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, notation

This is a quick notation question: when one writes $X: C[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, what does that mean exactly? Is $C[0,\infty)$ the space of continuous functions with a domain of $[0,\infty)$ and thus $X$ is a functional? If so, shouldn't the range be a set of functions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is just a function from $C[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Since nothing is said about linearity of $X$, it need not be a linear functional.

Comment: What is $C[0,\infty)$ in words? is it a space of continuous functions with domain $[0,\infty)$ as I supposed in the questin?

Comment: $C[0,\infty)$ is the set of all real valued continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with domain $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Co domain of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$. So range cannot contain functions.it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

$C[0,∞)$ is the space of continuous functions with a domain of $[0,∞)$. It doesn't mean that $X$ is a linear function(functional) but if you study functional analysis or linear operators then it will propably be.

Maybe $X$ gets a function $f$ to it's norm $\|f\|\in \Bbb R$ or $X$ gets a function $f$ to a point like $X(f)=f(a)$ for $a\in[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: good point. would you mind answering the rest of the question though so i can accept an answer?

Comment: @Alex,i couldn't write sooner because i went to sleep:P. now it's ok